# kableExtra - collapse_rows not working when linebreaks are present

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

As stated in the title, the collapse_rows function of kableExtra doesn't seem to work when linebreaks are present. Examples below will hopefully explain clearly.

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep("abc", 3), B = c(1,2,3))

table <- kable(df, format = "latex") %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "middle")

table
```

will produce:

[collapse_rows without linebreaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8sTK.png)

But

```
df <- data.frame(A = linebreak(rep("a\nb\nc", 3)), B = c(1,2,3))

table <- kable(df, format = "latex", escape = FALSE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "middle")

table
```

produces:

[collapse_rows with linebreaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KNsQ.png)

The only difference between the two code chunks being that in the second code chunk `linebreak` is wrapping the `A` column, `\n` is added two times to the string "abc" to make it "a\nb\nc", and `escape = FALSE` is added as an argument to the kable call.

I would still very much like them to collapse into a single cell. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `linebreak()` call, which applies different alignment to each of the three occurrences of the label, so `collapse_rows()` doesn't see them as the same thing.  That's probably a bug in the function, but it has an easy workaround:  just specify the alignment explicitly:

```
df <- data.frame(A = linebreak(rep("a\nb\nc", 3), align = "c"), 
                 B = c(1,2,3))

table <- kable(df, format = "latex", escape = FALSE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "middle")

table
```

[image]

Edited to add:  I just noticed that this was fixed in the devel version of `kableExtra`, but there hasn't been a new release in quite a while.  So your original code should work if you install the devel version using

```
remotes::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")
```